# rendering thousands of unique text labels using three.js

Tags: three.js, shader, label

[image: point cloud]

I have a `THREE.PointCloud` that contains a large amount of points.  In the screenshot above, each point is mapped to small purpleish circle.

I'm trying to figure out a way to display text labels beside each points.

My first attempt was to dynamically create text via the canvas and display the textures inside `THREE.Sprite` objects.  This achieved the look I was going for, but the performance hit was significant.  I quickly learned this wouldn't scale past just a few hundred points.

I'm thinking there may be a way to do this with shaders but I cannot figure out the approach. The method used in [animating a million letters](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/) used a texture of glyphs, and mapped the letters to the glyphs:

[image: glyph sheet]

I'm thinking I could do the same by creating a `THREE.Geometry` object and pushing the vertices and faces for each text letter of the labels.  The downside is that I want the labels to billboard so that they always face the camera.  [Billboarding in the vertex shader](http://www.geeks3d.com/20140807/billboarding-vertex-shader-glsl/) seems to be pretty straightforward.

My feeling is that there are already some examples out there that combine all of these ideas into a single working example.  Any suggestions on how to do large-scale text labels would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  You have to use a glyph sheet and render each character as a quad using two faces.

The process is outlined pretty well in [animating a million letters](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/)

I can get away with about a million on-screen characters before performance starts taking a hit.